# mercurial manifest case folding issue

Tags: mercurial

I discovered some case folding problem by running hg manifest under windows. Here is a segment of the manifest output.

src/include/a.h

src/Include/b.h

but they all appear to be under src/Include in my local windows file explorer view. I just wonder will it cause any problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can cause problems - on windows systems or mac systems where case-sensitivity is switched-off. Should you ever have a file with identical names inside those directories, then - provided my memory serves me well - mercurial on a system with case-insensitive file systems won't be able to checkout revisions where that seemingly "duplicate" file exists and mercurial will throw an error.

My advice: use directory and filenames such that there are no duplicates in paths when transferred to a case-insensitive file system, and also filenames unique enough so that it won't cause problems either.